# Should I let a library I downloaded change my settings/settings.inc.php file?

Tags: php, apache

I have a library I am trying to use. To install it I need to give it some permissions to write to:

```
settings/settings.inc.php (to store settings)
settings/files.inc.php – (store information about generated sitemap; only useful for small websites)
```

Should I allow it? Or is it too dangerous? I am not sure what those files really do :) but it seems important :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you really want to use it. It *seems* it's just just trying to write the settings and maybe the files for caching. But to be sure, look in the source code.
Or check Google if this library is known as legit

Maybe giving some more information about the library (name?!) would help too.

Comment: the library name is phpSitemapNG - its basically for making site maps

Comment: Well, it's typical for larger libraries to write something into files (after install, logging, etc) so I think you should give the rights. If it was malicious in the first place the code itself would contain it

Comment: interesting...by the way, do you know how to give rights like that to that program? Is it something usually in the library or those files?

Comment: Yeah usually I have to give the rights to write into files. In UNIX based system you'd use chmod. So for writing permissions for everyone, you'd enter `chmod 666`. To investigate further you can read [this article](http://www.zzee.com/solutions/chmod-help.shtml) or just google chmod, there is plenty of information in the internet, because that's a very common task :)